# include fade between text slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, slide, fade

I'm attempting to make it so that there is a fade transition between these text slides with swipe ability instead of just arrow keys. I'd highly appreciate any help.

The link to the page is http://shahrukhkhanstuff.com/zentests/reachoutproject/index.php

This is the javascript I'm using:

```
    $(document.documentElement).keyup(function (e) {
    var $activeslide = $('.slides.active');
    if (e.keyCode == 39) {
        if ($activeslide.next('.slides').length) {
            $targetslide = $activeslide.next('.slides');
        }
        else {}
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 37) {
        if ($activeslide.prev('.slides').length) {
            $targetslide = $activeslide.prev('.slides');
        }
        else {}
    }
    $targetslide.addClass('active');
    $activeslide.removeClass('active');
});
```

Comment: You mean swipe on the touch devices?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to add swipe for touch devices*

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about using swipe, but here's a CSS solution you can use for fading in and out.

```
.slides {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 1s;
    position: absolute;
}

.slides.active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: thank you!!! The fade is one part that i was just looking for. 
The only issue I can't figure out now is to make it able to be SWIPED or even click-to-fade into next slide through touch devices.

Comment: For swipe, you'd be best including some other library. HammerJS and QuoJS seem some of the best ones for that. http://quojs.tapquo.com/ http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/